# Setup Java EE environment on Mac

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, development-environment

I am new to Java EE. I want to setup Java EE environment to begin developing web applications. I read through articles on internet but they seems to be confusing. My question is that is there any one time installer for Java EE development environment setup? I mean like we have for PHP is that WAMP, XMPP, LAMP etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single installer, but two will be enough - you will need an IDE - the most popular are [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/). And you will need a Java EE distribution which comes in the form of a Java EE compliant application server - the most popular ones are [JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas) and [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/). With both IDE and server all you have to do is unpack them into folders of your choice.

The JavaEE distibution of  NetBeans already includes GlassFish - even less to do for you ;)

As a prerequisite, you will need an installed [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), a JRE won't do.

EDIT : In order to control the server and deploy from eclipse you will have to tell it where your application server is - there are according plugins [for Glassfish](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/eclipse/indigo/) and [for JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/tools).

I'm not sure about JBoss integration with NetBeans - never done it, but NB intagrates seamlessly with Glassfish.

Glassfish incldes a [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) (JavaDB) distribution, and JBoss includes a [H2 DB](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) distribution which both will be enough to start.

Using MySQL or other databases will require a bit of configuration, so if you're just starting - don't bother yet.

Comment: You mean after choosing eclipse I have to install Glassfish and it will work? OR I have to manually tell eclipse that Mr. Eclipse here is glassfish and use it? Secondly How about database such as mysql? Will it include in GlassFish? Sorry if my questions are way too newbie.

Comment: @al0neevenings - have added more details

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use Eclipse Juno Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers,

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr1

Comment: Does this include all the necessary items such as WebServer, JDK, MySQL or other database for developing web apps using java?

Comment: No - you might want to use docker and/or macports to complete your IDE